# MDX. Получить количество уникальных людей, отобранных по последнему визиту в диапазоне дат

Tags: sql, sql-server, olap, ssas

Всем добрый день.

Я новичок в кубах, а в компании нет опытного кубиста у кого можно было бы спросить.

Есть небольшой куб с двумя измерениями: Time Dimension и Customer Dimension, в каждом по одному атрибуту Day и ID соответственно. Есть факты с мерами: PurchaseCount, PurchaseSum, Customer Distinct Count, Last Visit.

Стоит задача найти последние даты покупок людей, затем наложить на результат фильтр диапазона дат, после чего вывести количество людей.

Помогите пожалуйста, потому что найти примеры последних дат можно на msdn, а вот как применить фильтр именно к результату я не совсем понимаю, что только не пробовал и как только не извращался) и having и filter(...filter(...[Last Visit]...)...) все равно не работает, либо работает неправильно.